# Function returns invalid answer in FIrefox ( Javascript )

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am trying to fetch the age of a user from a user input i.e., Date of birth.
The date of birth of the user is in format (18-Aug-2008) (DD-MMM-YYYY).

I am providing the input in a function that determines the age and returns the age.

```
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    console.log(age);
    return age;
}
```

The Above function returns age perfectly in CHrome and Edge, But in firefox i am not able to fetch proper age. 
If the date of birth is (18-Aug-2008) 
Age returned in Chrome : 12 
Age returned in Edge : 12 
Age returned in Firefox: 4028

Please help me to fix this.

Thank You,
Afras Khan

Comment: See any of the dozens, possibly hundreds, of other questions about date/time parsing. JavaScript's `Date` only parses a single specified format (and another that isn't specified, but is universally supported). Your input isn't in either of those formats. You'll have to parse it yourself, or use a library to parse it.

Comment: I've just tried this in Firefox and get `NaN` as the `birthDate` value is seen as an invalid date.

Comment: Try replacing the hyphens with spaces.  Firefox will then accept it as a date.